# Need to delete every file that includes a specific word

Tags: python, directory, delete-file

I am trying to make a button that deletes all files that include the word "cast" because I have many files with that word included but all with a different prefix e.g. "(copy1)".

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Matt le blanc terminator")
root.geometry('400x250')

def terminate():
    if os.path.exists('cast.*'):
        os.remove('cast.*')
    else:
        print("File does not exist")
        
TBtn = tk.Button(text="TERMINATE",fg="red", bg="black", command=terminate, width=100, height=50)
TBtn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `glob` to get the the list of all such names and then just use `os.remove()`. Give more information, like a full name of the file and is 'cast' on the first or the last or in between the file name and what is the extension of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is simpler to list the directory and then check file per file if contains "cast" in the name

```
import os 
all_files = os.listdir()
for f in all_files:
    file_without_extension = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
    if "cast" in file_without_extension:
        os.remove(f)
```